# How to reduce CE Cache Size?

Tags: ee2, ee, ce-cache

I installed the CE Cache plugin on my ExpressionEngine v. 2.11.1.  Everything started working well the first two weeks but now it is taking too long to load a page from the site, and sometimes I got disconnected.

Here is my current configuration:

```
//// CE cache settings
$config['ce_cache_drivers'] = 'file|db';
$config['ce_cache_file_permissions'] = 0644;
$config['ce_cache_dir_permissions'] = 0775;
$config['ce_cache_seconds'] = 300;
```

Next, doing a research on my server I found that the  ce_cache_db_driver table is around 10 GB size  and the file cache directory is some GBs on size... This is going to consume all my hard drive and my DB.. Also, since it is a really big cache, I am not able to view the files on the EE Control Panel.

Any ideas about how to purge both, DB and File Cache?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the rows in the database you could do this:

```
TRUNCATE `exp_ce_cache_tagged_items`;
```

And

```
TRUNCATE `exp_ce_cache_db_driver`;
```

To remove them in the file system you could:

```
rm -rf /path/to/your/cache/directory/
```

I'd guess that if your cache is that large that perhaps you have not set up CE Cache correctly or your site is not strict about using canonical urls...

Am also curious why you would have such a short duration on the cache.

Comment: Hi AllInOne: It is a newspaper site and the articles are updated every 5 minutes so a new page has to be loaded when a new entry has been entered. Any idea about a recommended cache time and how to setup CE cache to purge automatically the tables and files as well?